# How to convert JSON array to objects

Tags: json, go

I have following json

```
{"data":{"0":{"0":"1","1":"Test1","2":"Test2","DT_RowId":"row_1"}}}
```

I want to remove the outer level index

I want as below

```
{"data":[{"0":"1","1":"Test1","2":"Test2","DT_RowId":"row_1"}]}
```

This should be done in Go.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problem are you experiencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data1 := make(map[string]map[string]interface{})
    s1 := `{"data":{"0":{"0":"1","1":"Test1","2":"Test2","DT_RowId":"row_1"}}}`
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s1), &data1)
    if err != nil {
        // check error
    }

    data2 := make(map[string][]interface{})
    data2["data"] = []interface{}{data1["data"]["0"]}
    s2, err := json.Marshal(data2)
    if err != nil {
        // check error
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", s2)
    // result will be:
    // {"data":[{"0":"1","1":"Test1","2":"Test2","DT_RowId":"row_1"}]}
}
```

You can check it in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AGAosU6pBSB).

And don't forget to check data before using it, like:

```
// instead of:
data2["data"] = []interface{}{data1["data"]["0"]}

// you must have something like:
val1, ok := data1["data"]
if !ok { ... }
// and
val2, ok := val1["0"]
if !ok { ... }
```